Method to increase incorming request size in envoy proxy
Description:
I am getting the below error when the incoming request size is greater than 300 MB. The istio proxy sidecar container throws the below error and doesn't allow the request. How to increase the threshold value here.
Increased the max size of the request using envoy filter (parameter : max_request_bytes)
ERROR:
503 UC upstream_reset_before_response_started{connection_termination}
Increased the max size of the request using envoy filter (parameter : max_request_bytes) . The error occured is 503 , not (431 payload too large) when request size is larger.
